# Sort Javascript array of objects in place by property value with save keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, properties

How to sort array of objects by property 'cost' with holding string keys?

Start array :

```
aparts: {
    apart1 : {id: "1", status: 2, cost: 10033450},
    apart2 : {id: "2", status: 2, cost: 5214000},
    apart3 : {id: "3", status: 2, cost: 7314300},
    apart4 : {id: "4", status: 1, cost: 9261700}    
}
```

Want to array:

```
aparts: {
    apart2 : {id: "2", status: 2, cost: 5214000},
    apart3 : {id: "3", status: 2, cost: 7314300},
    apart4 : {id: "4", status: 1, cost: 9261700},
    apart1 : {id: "1", status: 2, cost: 10033450}   
}
```

Comment: You can not sort object properties (keys) officially

Comment: @Redu it's bad news

Comment: `aparts` is **NOT** an array. It's a regular object.

Comment: well these are json objects, not arrays. If you can also work with arrays then you could use libraries like lodash or alasql

Comment: In this case "sorting" means "reassigning keys", I think.

Comment: @DuncanThacker - have you actually looked at the desired result?

Comment: Ah, it's been edited - you're correct <discards draft answer>

Comment: So is any solutions of this task?

Comment: @DuncanThacker yep, sorry

Comment: Sorting is an "arrays only" job... You best place your objects in an array and then sort them happily.

Comment: @dsb do you actually mean arrays or objects? If you mean objects, there's no answer.

Comment: As @Redu says sorting is for arrays, this can be solved using reflection and iterating over the keys, placing them on an array, sorting the array and rebuilding the object. But i don't understand why is needed

Comment: @Redu thanks, try to do it. Sorry for question - your recommedation to improve knowledges of js ?

Comment: The order of properties in an object is not defined. So there is no point in even trying to rearrange them. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Alberto i have this incoming json and have to sort data by property to display in the required order

Comment: @dsb please answer Matt Burland question. There is no point on doing it

Comment: @MattBurland i have this incoming json and have to display data in Html in the required order (insert in divs, eg)

Comment: @dsb then it sounds like you need to transform it into an array. Something that actually is ordered

Comment: @MattBurland yep, try to do it. Thanks

Comment: Like everyone say an array is really want you need, something like -> `Object.keys(aparts).map((k) => {return {[k]:aparts[k]}}).sort((a,b) => a.cost - b.cost)` will transform into a sorted array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of properties is not guaranteed. See, for example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/1250301

If you want something ordered, then you need to use an array. The transformation is pretty straightforward:

```js
var aparts = {
    apart1 : {id: "1", status: 2, cost: 10033450},
    apart2 : {id: "2", status: 2, cost: 5214000},
    apart3 : {id: "3", status: 2, cost: 7314300},
    apart4 : {id: "4", status: 1, cost: 9261700}    
};

var arr = Object.keys(aparts).map(function(k) { return aparts[k]; }).sort(function(a,b) { return a.cost - b.cost });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const aparts = {
    apart1: {id:"1", status: 2, cost: 10033450},
    apart2: {id:"2", status: 2, cost: 5214000},
    apart3: {id:"3", status: 2, cost: 7314300},
    apart4: {id:"4", status: 1, cost: 9261700}    
};

const arr = 
  Object.keys(aparts)
  .map(k => (aparts[k]))
  .sort((a,b) => (a.cost - b.cost))
  .map(k => ({["apart" + k.id]: k}))
;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a Map. Which is what your irregular object matches.

```js
let aparts= {
    apart1: { id: "1", status: 2, cost: 10033450 },
    apart2: { id: "2", status: 2, cost: 5214000 },
    apart3: { id: "3", status: 2, cost: 7314300 },
    apart4: { id: "4", status: 1, cost: 9261700 }
};
let sorted = Object.entries(aparts).map(x => Object.assign(x[1], {
  apart: x[0]
})).sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost);

let result = new Map(sorted.map(x => ([x.apart, (delete x.apart, x)])));

console.log(...result)
```

Comment: @dsb I'd like to leave you with a thought... but I'm not sure you have anywhere to put it.

Comment: don't understand you